# Drag and drop gets executed but its not getting performed - webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have tried these two codes , it get executed but the action does not get performed ,Can any one tell me why?

```
//Type one approach
Actions action = new Actions(Browser.Driver);
IWebElement sourceElement = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(Filexpath));
IWebElement targetElement = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(NewXpath));

//Type two approach 
Actions Sourcebuilder = new Actions(Browser.Driver);
Actions SourceAction = Sourcebuilder.ClickAndHold(sourceElement);
Sourcebuilder.Build();
SourceAction.Perform();



/// move and drop
Actions builder = new Actions(Browser.Driver);
Actions action = builder.MoveToElement(targetElement);
builder.Release(targetElement);
builder.Build();
action.Perform();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
 Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
 ac.dragAndDrop(source element, target element);
 ac.build().perform();
```

It will click-and-hold at the location of the source element, moves to the location of the target element, then releases the mouse.

Or

```
 Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
 ac.dragAndDropBy(source element, xOffset, yOffset);
 ac.build().perform();
```

It will click-and-hold at the location of the source element, moves by a given offset, then releases the mouse.

Or

```
    Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
    ac.clickAndHold(onElement);
    ac.moveToElement(toElement); or ac.moveToElement(toElement, xOffset, yOffset);
    ac.build().perform();
```

It will do the action of the above two code.

I write this code on Java. You can convert in to your specified language.

Refereed from [Actions.](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)

Comment: If we have 2 or 3 drag and drop operations? then how can we run after first drag and drop operation completes.