# Automate drag & drop functionality [File Upload] using Selenium WebDriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I need to automate drag and drop functionality in C# but couldn't find the right way to do it! This is a file upload form and I need to automate drag and drop action there.

Experimented this way :

```c#
public void FileAttachment() {
    PageObjects.UploadFile.Click();
    Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id='fileUpload']div")).SendKeys("filepath");
    PageObjects.FileUploadSend.Click();
}
```

Help me getting through this rock!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag and drop gets executed but its not getting performed - webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830719/drag-and-drop-gets-executed-but-its-not-getting-performed-webdriver)

Comment: The code seems offbeat here. It is more towards `file upload` rather than `Drag and Drop`.

Comment: Exactly @pArAs! It's dragging a file from local path and dropping into the target element. It is not that both source and target in the same webpage!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using HTML5 drag and drop? I am stuck with the same issue, and seeing from the various threads, using HTML5 drag and drop has been bugged since few years ago and doesn't seem to be fixed. I found some alternative ways from github achieves, they require javascript execution though, as well as translating the code to C# : http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop

Comment: I'm looking it for a file upload, considering the source and the target is not on the same webpage, but the file is dragged from a local drive and dropped into the target!

Comment: In that case, you will need to use something else combined with Selenium. Selenium is limited to browser. You need something like AutoIt to drag your local file and then execute the rest of the Selenium code as far as I know.

Comment: Exactly! This is the key I was looking for! Appreciate your help @Memfisto!

Comment: @cashanzlo Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

After few research works, I wish to share how I fixed it!

`AutoIt` is an automation tool like Selenium but unlike Selenium it is used for Desktop Automation rather Web Automation. It automates mouse movements & keystrokes, desktop windows, buttons & forms.

Installing it and Referencing into the project makes it happen!

So code looks like,

```
public void FileAttachment()
{
        PageObjects.UploadFile.Click();
        Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id='fileUpload']div")).Click();
        AutoItX3 autoIt = new AutoItX3();
        autoIt.WinActive("Open"); //Differs from Browser to Browser
        autoIt.Send(@"C:Desktop\doccs\trialTest.txt");
        autoIt.Send("{ENTER}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        PageObjects.FileUploadSend.Click();
}
```