# Is there any alternative of using selenium dragAndDrop() in IE11 without using capability

Tags: javascript, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I tried with Actions dragAndDropBy() & robot class for IE11 where
WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver()
But no luck. Tried with robot class also.

dragAndDrop() is working with DesiredCapabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    cap.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
    WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

But mouse cursor also move for all click()

Is there any way we can drag the element to offset?

//====Tried with actions

```
WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_draganddrop.asp");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("locator")));
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("locator"));
actions( driver, ele);
Point p=ele.getLocation();
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.dragAndDropBy(ele, 200, 0).build().perform();
```

//====tried with robot class

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);    
    robot.mouseMove(p.getX()+150, p.getY());    
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);
```

without using DesiredCapabilities can we drag an element to offSet

Comment: Do you meet any error if not using DesiredCapabilities? Here are some resource about How to Drag and Drop in Selenium WebDriver, you could refer to them: [link1](https://www.guru99.com/drag-drop-selenium.html), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830719/drag-and-drop-gets-executed-but-its-not-getting-performed-webdriver)

Comment: i am not getting any error. But its simply goes to the next steps